# DL back-propagation: Does the loss function necessarily need to be calculated from the direct output from a network?

Tags: calculus

In deep learning, we typically pass the output of a network we are training along with a training sample (batched or not) into a loss function. We then take the gradient of this loss function with respect to the weights of the network and use the gradient to update the weights and minimize the loss.

I don't have the best grasp of the calculations involved in back-propagating this loss, so I am curious as to whether or not we can use values other than the direct output from the network to calculate the loss.

Practically, this could look like passing the output of the model and the training sample through another fully trained neural network before calculating the loss. We could take the respective outputs of this network (for the training sample and the output of the first network), calculate the MSE loss between the two outputs (which should be differentiable) and back-propagate the gradient of this loss back to the original network.

Comment: This will probably get a lot more activity over at [stats.se]

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I’ll ask over there.